# empty() and isset() returning incorrect result for properties of an object - PHP 7.3, Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7.3

**Environment:** PHP 7.3, Laravel 5.6

**Problem:** `empty()` and `isset()` are returning an incorrect result when the code runs in a browser, but the correct result when run over a Tinker command line session.

---

**Expected Behavior:**

- `isset()` to return `true` when the property exists, `false` when it does not
- `empty()` to return `true` when the property exists and is not `null`, `false` otherwise

---

**Example: `empty()`**

```
if(!empty($practiceArea->hero_video)) { 
   ... some HTML
}
```

This `!empty` always evaluates to `false`, even though `$practiceArea->hero_video` is set and I can see its value through `echo` or `var_dump`.

And `empty($practiceArea->hero_video`) always evaluates to `true`, as I learned after unsuccessfully trying the alternative:

```
if(empty($practiceArea->hero_video) === false) {
```

---

**Example: `isset()`**

`isset($practiceArea->hero_video)` always incorrectly returns `false`.

---

**Current Hacky Workaround:**

```
$video = $practiceArea->hero_video;
if(!empty($video)) { 
   ... some HTML
}
```

This works exactly as expected - `$video` takes the value of `$practiceArea->hero_video`, then `!empty($video)` returns `true` if we have a value and `false` if the value is `null`.

---

**Examples of expected result in Tinker session:**

```
>>> $pa = PracticeArea::find(11)
>>> ... an object is returned
>>> $pa->hero_video
=> "//www.youtube.com/embed/0qisGSwZym4"
>>> if(empty($pa->hero_video)) echo "Empty"; else echo "Not empty";
Not empty
>>> if(!empty($pa->hero_video)) echo "Not empty"; else echo "Empty";
Not empty
```

`isset()` also works as expected in Tinker:

```
>>> isset($pa->hero_video)
=> true
>>> !isset($pa->hero_video)
=> false
```

---

**Reproducing:**

I assume that our `PracticeArea` class is using magic getters, because it extends Laravel 5.6's [Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) class, which does include `__get` and `__isset` methods.

Below is the abridged `PracticeArea` class. Happy to post the whole thing, but there are no methods or properties relevant to this.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;

class PracticeArea extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'practice_areas';

}
```

---

`var_dump($practiceAreas)`

```
object(App\PracticeArea)#506 (29) { 
    ["translatable":protected]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "name" 
        [1]=> string(11) "description" 
        [2]=> string(7) "heading" 
        [3]=> string(4) "body" 
        [4]=> string(4) "slug" 
    } 
    ["table":protected]=> string(14) "practice_areas" 
    ["fillable":protected]=> array(11) { 
        [0]=> string(25) "practice_area_category_id" 
        [1]=> string(11) "metadata_id" 
        [2]=> string(4) "name" 
        [3]=> string(11) "description" 
        [4]=> string(7) "heading" 
        [5]=> string(4) "body" 
        [6]=> string(10) "sort_order" 
        [7]=> string(9) "published" 
        [8]=> string(10) "hero_video" 
        [9]=> string(10) "hero_image" 
        [10]=> string(4) "slug" 
    } 
    ["translates":protected]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "name" 
        [1]=> string(11) "description"
        [2]=> string(7) "heading" 
        [3]=> string(4) "body" 
        [4]=> string(4) "slug" 
    } 
    ["translate_relation":protected]=> string(14) "practice_areas" 
    ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" 
    ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" 
    ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" 
    ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) 
    ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } 
    ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) 
    ["exists"]=> bool(true) 
    ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) 
    ["attributes":protected]=> array(15) { 
        ["id"]=> int(11) 
        ["practice_area_category_id"]=> int(1) 
        ["metadata_id"]=> int(26) 
        ["name"]=> string(19) "Workplace Accidents" 
        ["description"]=> string(30) "Workplace injuries description" 
        ["heading"]=> string(30) "Workplace Accidents & Injuries" 
        ["body"]=> string(1246) "
```

Comment: out of interest, what happens if you created a public get method and used isset/empty accordingly?

Comment: While perhaps an interesting question, especially the difference between environments… if `$video = $practiceArea->hero_video` works without error, i.e. `$practiceArea->hero_video` is guaranteed to never raise any error about undefined properties (Eloquent models probably do, I have no idea…!?), then you don't need and shouldn't use `empty` or `isset` at all.

Comment: @treyBake I will try that later today and update the post with the result.

Comment: @deceze In the case where `hero_video` is empty, we need to render a different block of HTML which utilizes the alternative `hero_image`.

Comment: `empty` means *does not exist or is falsey*. If you don't need to worry about the "not exists" part because it can't not exist, then you can just use the good old "is falsey" operator, a.k.a. `== false` a.k.a. `!`.

Comment: I know it will always exist. But this property can be changed by users via our custom CMS, so what I have to worry about is if it's something like "" or " " (rather than just `null`). I could add a string length check to my current workaround to accomplish this, and could furthermore add validation for this property in the relevant controller. My larger concern here is the general unpredictability of `isset()` and `empty()`, as we may legitimately need these in other parts of the application. I'm trying to understand why this is happening, so we can avoid potential trouble elsewhere.

Comment: So, `isset`/`empty` on classes with magic getters require the class' cooperation to work correctly. Eloquent seems to either be buggy, or it has the assumption you should never need to use `isset`/`empty` with its properties, since it'll always return *a value* for any given property and never raise an error. So then you should not use `isset`/`empty` with it and just check its value, like `if (!$practiceArea->hero_video)`. That'll have the exact same effect as you'd expect `empty` to have.

Comment: Your var_dump is capped, what does it say about your attributes in `["attributes":protected]=> array(15) {`

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` on **non-public** class properties need an implementation of `public function __isset()` in the class to work properly.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset

> `__isset()` is triggered by calling `isset()` or `empty()` on
>   inaccessible properties.

Your specific problem is coming from the implementation in Laravel:

```
public function __isset($key)
{
    return $this->offsetExists($key);
}

public function offsetExists($offset)
{
    return ! is_null($this->getAttribute($offset));
}
```

The method `getAttribute()` does not inspect all class properties plus **it checks for `! is_null` which is not fully equivalent to `isset()` / `empty()`**.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php

```
// If the attribute exists in the attribute array or has a "get" mutator we will
// get the attribute's value. Otherwise, we will proceed as if the developers
// are asking for a relationship's value. This covers both types of values.
if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) ||
    $this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
    return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
}
```

I would try to investigate the content of the `$attributes` property from that Trait.

Comment: OP points out that the class is a Laravel model which contains `__isset()` implementation

Comment: @morph yea but the implementation does not cover OPs concerns